# What is a better word instead of "set" in this context?

Tags: word-choice

I have this sentence

> The System shall allow customers to **set** their addresses.

I think that the word **set** is not a good fit here. Would a word such as **define**, **determine**, or **locate** be better here? Or can you think of an even better suggestion?

Comment: I think any of the suggestions could be OK, but more context as to what "their addresses" are, and how they are set, may help to pick the best word to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some suggestions:

> The System shall allow customers to **insert** their addresses.
>
> The System shall allow customers to **specify** their addresses.
>
> The System shall allow customers to **provide** their addresses.